# Convert readable time string to datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an alarm clock app, I want when the user enter's "5:00 PM", the system store it as datetime.
How do I convert '5:00 pm' to a datetime.
If it is already past 5:00 pm and the user enters '5:00 pm', the system should assume the user means tomorrow's '5:00 pm' and return the appropriate datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a previous answer, I figure out.

```
time_string = '5:00 pm' # mock of user input

date_time = DateTime.parse time_string
date_time += 1.day if Time.now > date_time 
return date_time
```